# Write to FIFO only if it exists

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, fifo

Most of the examples that I see about writing to a FIFO say to use the `echo` or `cat` commands and redirect stdout to the file. E.g.,

```
echo 'a' > /tmp/my_fifo
```

However, this will create a regular file if the FIFO does not already exist. Is there some analog to `mkfifo` but for writing that would fail if it doesn't exist? That is, something similar to:

```
echo 'a' | write-to-existing-file /tmp/my_fifo
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the BASH manual:

```
-p file
   True if file exists and is a named pipe (FIFO).
```

So:

```
if [[ -p /tmp/my_fifo ]]; then
    # commands to execute
fi
```

The question has the tag, *bash*. In context, the usage of `[[` and `]]` is specific to BASH. (Tangentially, `[[` and `]]` also work with zsh and the Korn shell.) See [BashFAQ/031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031). Portable scripts should be written with `[` and `]` which work in all POSIX shells.

Comment: +1 for using the `-p` test.

Comment: That's [POSIX standard for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), so you don't need the `[[ ]]`.  `[ -p /tmp/my_fifo ]` will do fine.

Comment: @Wildcard The difference is important. Thanks!